# Проблема SSH в Glassfish

Tags: windows, сервер, ssh, glassfish, windows-server-2012

Всем доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: мне необходимо создать отказоустойчивую систему на Glassfish 4.x (один кластер, 2 нода). Необходимо, чтобы это всё работало на Windows Server (я использую 2 виртуалки Windows Server 2012 R2). Руководствуясь одним из мануалов, один из нодов необходимо перевести, скажем так, в тип SSH, но при попытке смены пишет, что пользователю не хватает прав, чтобы осуществить это (но при этом на сервере видно, что подключение было). Захожу на сервера, соответственно, под учетной записью "Администратор".
Код ошибки:

> SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED: The user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.

Как SSH сервер использую freeSSHd. Через Putty подключается без проблем.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!
[image: Ошибка на сервере Glassfish]

[image: Подключение на 2-м сервере по SSH]